# How do I add my Dapp to https://www.stateofthedapps.com/?

Tags: dapps

If I create a Dapp or start development on an Ethereum Dapp, what's the easiest way to get my Dapp listed on https://www.stateofthedapps.com/?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Submit your DApp using the [Submit a DApp](https://www.stateofthedapps.com/dapps/submit/new) form on the [State of the DApps](https://www.stateofthedapps.com/) site:

[image: State of the DApps]
**Step 1**: Click on the **(Submit a DApp)** button on the top menu.

[image: Complete the form]
**Step 2**: Fill the form to complete your submission.

Your DApp submission will typically be processed by the next business day.

Answer (score 4):

Send an email to dapps@ethercasts.com or create a [ticket on github](https://github.com/EtherCasts/state-of-the-dapps/issues) with the following details:

- title:
- description:
- url:
- github repo:
- maintainers:
- status:
- license:

There is a [Google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VdRMFENPzjL2V-vZhcc_aa5-ysf243t5vXlxC2b054g/edit#gid=0) organizing all the DApps.

Comment: These instructions are no longer correct as of October 2017.